# Does freeing locked memory unlock the corresponding pages?

Tags: c++, c, unix, memory, posix

It's clear how you can combine `mlockall()` and `malloc()` to lock all the pages allocated by a process during its life. What is not clear to me by reading the documentation is whether freeing **already locked** memory implies an automatic unlock of the corresponding pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `free` returns the memory to the system (i.e. it was allocated with `mmap` and will be freed with `munmap`), then the lock will automatically be removed when it is unmapped. This is typically the case with large allocations.

If `free` returns the memory to a heap managed within the process, then the lock will remain. This is typically the case for small allocations.

On GNU/Linux, you can use `mallopt` to get and set the threshold for allocations using `mmap`; the default (on my computer, at least) is 128kb. On other Unix flavours, you might need to use `mmap` directly if you need that level of control.